# Highcharts static line with background color below it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need a "minimum" style line that is spread across value `y` and is static at it. What I have so far:

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        value: <?=$product[0]['current_price']?>
    }]
}
```

Now what I want to do, is take the background below this line, and color it. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately background under plotLine is not supported. You can only use Renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer and add extra shape, or use plotBand, below plotLine.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands

Comment: yAxis.plotBands was what I was looking for. Thanks!